# Format Date/Time in XAML in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have a Silverlight 4 application. I have a C# DateTime object that I'm binding to my UI. I want this DateTime to be in the format of `dd/mm/yyyy` time (TimeZone). For instance, today would be displayed as

```
04/07/2011 at 01:13 p.m. (EST)
```

Is there a way to do this `XAML`? Or do I need to build a converter?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{}{0:MM/dd/yyyy a\\t h:mm tt}'}" />
```

will return you

04/07/2011 at 1:28 PM (-04)

Comment: I love these F~€#~€ weird string formats ... who the hell can recall them (talking about the {}0: part).

Comment: This is correct, except your quotes around the format string should be single quotes  
  
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:'MM/dd/yyyy a\\t h:mm tt'}}" />

Comment: I had to put my single quotes in a different place: Text="{Binding startDate, StringFormat='{}{0:MM/dd/yy}'}"

Comment: If you're using a `Label` rather than `TextBlock`, recall that you need to use `ContentStringFormat` instead of setting the Binding StringFormat.

Comment: all these work for a textblock or textbox but inside a datepicker itself the formats does not work. Any idea how to do it in the date picker

Answer (score 66):

You can use [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in Silverlight 4 to provide a custom formatting of the value you bind to.

## Dates

The date formatting has a huge range of options.

For the DateTime of “April 17, 2004, 1:52:45 PM”

You can either use a set of standard formats (standard formats)…

```
StringFormat=f : “Saturday, April 17, 2004 1:52 PM”
StringFormat=g : “4/17/2004 1:52 PM”
StringFormat=m : “April 17”
StringFormat=y : “April, 2004”
StringFormat=t : “1:52 PM”
StringFormat=u : “2004-04-17 13:52:45Z”
StringFormat=o : “2004-04-17T13:52:45.0000000”
```

… or you can create your own date formatting using letters (custom formats)

```
StringFormat=’MM/dd/yy’ : “04/17/04”
StringFormat=’MMMM dd, yyyy g’ : “April 17, 2004 A.D.”
StringFormat=’hh:mm:ss.fff tt’ : “01:52:45.000 PM”
```

Answer (score 11):

you can also use just

```
StringFormat=d
```

in your datagrid column for date time showing

finally it will be

```
   <sdk:DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Path=DeliveryDate,StringFormat=d}" Header="Delivery date" Width="*" />
```

the out put will look like

[image]

Comment: What if I want Day/Month/Year?

Comment: Use  StringFormat = dd-MMMM-yy

Answer (score 7):

In SL5 I found this to work:

```
<TextBlock Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding JustificationDate, StringFormat=dd-MMMM-yy hh:mm}">
<TextBlock Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding JustificationDate, StringFormat='Justification Date: \{0:dd-MMMM-yy hh:mm\}'}">
```

Answer (score 6):

C#: try this

- yyyy(yy/yyy) - years
- MM - months(like '03'), MMMM - months(like 'March')
- dd - days(like 09), ddd/dddd - days(Sun/Sunday)
- hh - hour 12(AM/PM), HH - hour 24
- mm - minute
- ss - second

Use some delimeter,like this:

1. MessageBox.Show(DateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
   example result: "2014-09-30"
2. empty format string:
   MessageBox.Show(DateValue.ToString());
   example result: "30.09.2014 0:00:00"

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(DateValue.ToString())` this output depends on the culture of Thread executing it (if not set its the system culture)

Answer (score 2):

For me this worked:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date , StringFormat=g}" Width="130"/>
```

If want to show seconds also using G instead of g :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date , StringFormat=G}" Width="130"/>
```

Also if want for changing date type to another like Persian , using Language :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date , StringFormat=G}" Width="130" Language="fa-IR"/>
```