# How do I format a DataGrid cell so a time entry from SQL will show up as hh:mm tt?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, xaml, wpfdatagrid

If the entry in my SQL table is 09:00:00 my cells either show up as something like 09:00:00 or if i throw in a string format like this:

```
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=tin, StringFormat=\{0:hh\\:mm\}}"  Header="Time In:"/>
```

I get 9:00. How do i make it formatted for a short time string like "09:00 AM"?

I have tried using StringFormat=t and it makes the cell blank. Any use of "t" and the cell goes blank. I am really in a pickle here.

The DataGrid is populated with a dataset named displayGrid. entryGrid is the DataGrid object.
        entryGrid.ItemsSource = displayGrid.Tables[0].DefaultView;

What I am looking for here is what to throw in the XAML to format this correctly. I need to go from 09:00:00 in my SQL 2008 Table to 09:00 AM in my datagrid. I am using C#.Net and XAML in VS 2012. I am super new to coding so I am sure it is a simple mistake or syntax error. Thank you for any help you can give.

EDIT:

I have even gone back, tried autogenerating the columns with the following code to format the cell:

```
 private void ResultsDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            DataGridTextColumn dataGridTextColumn = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
            if (dataGridTextColumn.Header.ToString().Equals("wkdate"))
            {
                dataGridTextColumn.Binding.StringFormat = "{0:d}";
            }
            if(dataGridTextColumn.Header.ToString().Equals("tin"))
            {
                dataGridTextColumn.Binding.StringFormat = "{0:t}";

            }
        }
    }
```

works for the date but not the time! This is driving me bonkers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps this will help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584948/format-date-time-in-xaml-in-silverlight

Comment: Yeah I spent a lot of time on that article prior to this post but to no avail. I thought it would for sure be the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your format, you could update your existing XAML Code and write as below:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=tin, StringFormat=\{0:hh:mm tt\}}"  Header="Time In:"/>
```

Hope this helps

Alternatively, Could you could you the below. I am sure this is working as i have used it in many project.

CS File Code:

```
 [ValueConversion(typeof(DateTime), typeof(string))]
    public class StringTime : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Members
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null || value.ToString() == "")
            {
                return "";
            }
            String str = ((DateTime)value).ToString("hh:mm tt");
            return str;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null || value.ToString() == "")
            {
                return value;
            }
            DateTime dtr = DateTime.MinValue.Date;
            dtr = dtr.AddYears(1899);
            if (value == null)
                return dtr;
            dtr = dtr.AddHours(double.Parse((value.ToString().Substring(0, 2))));
            dtr = dtr.AddMinutes(double.Parse((value.ToString().Substring(3, 2))));
            if(value.ToString().Substring(7, 2) == "PM")
                dtr = dtr.AddHours(12);

            return dtr;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

XAML File:

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <custom:StringTime x:Key="StringTime" />
    </Page.Resources>

DataGrid Column Code:

    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=tin, Converter={StaticResource StringTime}}"  Header="Time In:"/>
```

Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Again, this just makes the cell blank. I think there may be a deeper issue because all the code I have tried should work, its just when I try to format for the AM PM it goes blank. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @JMac I have updated the solution with the details description, a bit lengthy but works like great.

Comment: OK I almost there. The last issue is getting the StringTime.cs to be picked up by the xaml. I have custom as a defined namespace in the WPFApplication and stringtime is a class in there.... so shouldnt it be shown as existing in the namespace? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Ok so i used your code to get the data type of the info and learned that SQL server's "Time" type is pulled across as a timespan, not a date time! Now I feel super dumb but will be using your code to convert the timespan to a displayable time. Thanks for all your help!