# Flexing date format in XAML at runtime

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

Based on a setting in my application I need to be able to show different formats of showing a Date in XAML. For example it needs to be either in `"yyyy/MM/dd"` format or in `"MM/dd/yyyy"` format.

What are some ways that I can achieve this?  Please note that the places in my application that I need to handle this are limited so even a "fix on the spot" type of solution would work in my case too.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ValueConverter for this. Just replace YourApplicationSettings.YearFirst with wherever you're pulling the setting from.

```cs
public class DateTime2FlexibleDateString : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dt = value as DateTime?
        if (dt== null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var dateTime = dt.Value;

        if (YourApplicationSettings.YearFirst)
        {
            return dateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        }

        return dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then either in each xaml file that needs it, or in a App.xaml (or a resource dictionary added to App.xaml), add a static resource for your converter.

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:DateTime2FlexibleDateString x:Key="DateTime2FlexibleDateString" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And then when you bind to the date, specify the converter.

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDateTimeVariable, Converter={StaticResource DateTime2FlexibleDateString}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context of what you are doing, but if you are binding to a DateTime then you can alter the StringFormat property like so:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDateTimeVariable, StringFormat='yyyy/MM/dd'}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDateTimeVariable, StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy'}" />
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5584983/1624581) is a good example of some different format options that be achieved like this.

Comment: Yes that's correct but my question is how do I "flex" those string formats? some user may set that setting and magically I want them to see first format, some other user may set that setting and magically I want them to see another format

Comment: Oh I see... good idea... Let's me just keep it here a little longer to see if other people have other ideas or not. Thanks

Comment: @DevWannaBe I've just realised that my previous comment (which I have now deleted) was incorrect. Because StringFormat is not a DependencyProperty you cannot bind to it. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4010782/1624581) answer provides a way to get around that problem but it isn't entirely ideal.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I think we can't do that either, because Silverlight as far as I know only supports one binding but in WPF we can do two bindings, which is what that example is using.

Comment: Maybe I can use a Converter?

Comment: The converter approach is going to be your best bet.