# Binding string property to textblock and apply custom date format

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have textblock in a wpf application where I am binding a string property which displays the date and time. Is there a way to apply StringFormat on a string property to format the date content. I tried as follows but it dosent work. Please help.

In the Model the property is

```
   public string alertTimeStamp { get; set; }
```

In the view I am trying

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="25,5,0,0" Text="{Binding alertTimeStamp, StringFormat=0:dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}"></TextBlock>
```

the output is still 7/25/2016 12:20:23 PM

Comment: Try this possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584948/format-date-time-in-xaml-in-silverlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an IValueConverter to change your `string` object to `DateTime`. Something like this.

```
public class StringToDateValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return DateTime.Parse(value.ToString());
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Of course, you will want to implement some form of validation logic, which I've excluded for the sake of simplicity.

The markup...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:StringToDateValueConverter x:Key="converter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="25,5,0,0" Text="{Binding alertTimeStamp, Converter={StaticResource converter}, StringFormat=dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue here is that `alertTimeStamp` is already a string, so it cannot be altered via the `StringFormat` property.

I would recommend having a second property:

```
public DateTime AlertTimeStampDateTime
{
    get { return DateTime.Parse(this.alertTimeStamp); }
}
```

Then bind the `AlertTimeStampDateTime` property to the `<TextBlock />` object with the same `StringFormat` property.

Additionally, you can create a class that implements `IValueConverter` that does the same things. You can either do a `StringToDateTime` converter, and still use the `StringFormat` property if you want it more adaptable, or you can do `TimestampConverter` and have it change the `string` to a `DateTime`, format the DateTime with the format string above, and output the `string` itself. In this iteration, you wouldn't need your `StringFormat` property.

Comment: Sure let me give it a try.